# Token refresh store to allow refresh_token

Tags: identityserver4, openid

I have `IS4` configured and all works fine except `refresh_token` where I get BAD REQUESTS (400) back all the time.

I have implemented the `PersistedGrantStore` to store the tokens since reading the logs I could see:

```
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.589|TRACE|Processing token request. |IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.616|DEBUG|Start token request. |IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.624|DEBUG|Start client validation |IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.638|DEBUG|Start parsing Basic Authentication secret |IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.638|DEBUG|Start parsing for secret in post body |IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.701|DEBUG|client id without secret found |IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.701|DEBUG|Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser |IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser|type=PostBodySecretParser
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.720|DEBUG|Secret id found: autosmoraga_transportes_mobile_app |IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser|id=autosmoraga_transportes_mobile_app
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.734|TRACE|Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator |IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore|validatorType=IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.749|DEBUG|client configuration validation for client autosmoraga_transportes_mobile_app succeeded. |IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore|clientId=autosmoraga_transportes_mobile_app
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.749|DEBUG|Public Client - skipping secret validation success |IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.766|DEBUG|Client validation success |IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.785|TRACE|Calling into token request validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator |IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint|type=IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.799|DEBUG|Start token request validation |IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.825|DEBUG|Start validation of refresh token request |IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.856|TRACE|Start refresh token validation |IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator|
    2020/09/01 17:57:25.928|DEBUG|refresh_token grant with value: lSWqDibFzKevkEI6KMNQyGimeK7MS7Yrjenk34XEDNQ
     not found in store. |IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultRefreshTokenStore|grantType=refresh_token, key=lSWqDibFzKevkEI6KMNQyGimeK7MS7Yrjenk34XEDNQ
2020/09/01 17:57:25.939|WARN|Invalid refresh token |IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator|
2020/09/01 17:57:25.961|WARN|Refresh token validation failed. aborting, {"ClientId":"XXX", "ClientName":"XXX", "GrantType":"refresh_token", "Raw":{"client_id":"XXX","redirect_uri\n":"http:\/\/localhost:8100\/auth-callback","grant_type":"refresh_token","refresh_token":"***REDACTED***"}} |IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator|details={
  "ClientId": "XXXX",
  "ClientName": "XXX",
  "GrantType": "refresh_token",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "XXXX",
    "redirect_uri\n": "http://localhost:8100/auth-callback",
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": "***REDACTED***"
  }
}
```

I have registered the `.AddPersistedGrantStore<PersistedGrantStore>()` method however I still can see in the logs that `DefaultRefreshTokenStore` is being called however I see in the database I have records of type `refresh_token` stored. I'm not sure if I'm missing something. All works fine except the refresh token part. The client configuration is set with online access enabled:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "XXXX",
                    ClientName = "XXX",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "myapi" },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {
                        $"{mobileBaseUrl}/auth-callback",
                        $"{mobileAppBaseUrl}auth-callback",
                        $"{mobileAppOrigin}/auth-callback",
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {
                         $"{mobileBaseUrl}/end-session",
                         $"{mobileAppBaseUrl}end-session",
                         $"{mobileAppOrigin}/end-session",
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {
                        mobileBaseUrl,
                        mobileAppOrigin
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                }
```

so I'm not entirely sure what else to check. For reference I have the issue fully explained here: https://github.com/wi3land/ionic-appauth/issues/33

Comment: Can you try adding `offline_access` scope when initiating a request for an authorization code?

Comment: The scope offline_access is present in the whole process as in its in the list of scopes I have configured my client with. That’s the thing I wanted to use it to perform refresh token requests but it doesn’t seem to work properly. Any other hint or idea about what could be going on?

Comment: Ill try to replicate it, will get back to u

Comment: Did you manage to replicate the problem?